# boost::phoenix with VS2008

Tags: c++, boost-phoenix

Simple example using boost::phoenix:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

namespace ph = boost::phoenix;
namespace place = boost::phoenix::placeholders;

struct A
{
    int val_;
    explicit A(int i) : val_(i) {}
    int foo() { return val_;}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> coll;
    coll.push_back(A(2));
    coll.push_back(A(4));
    coll.push_back(A(5));
    coll.push_back(A(7));

    std::vector<A>::const_iterator cit;
    cit = std::find_if(coll.begin(), coll.end(), ph::bind(&A::foo, place::_1) % 2 == 1);
    int val = (*cit).val_;

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles but there are some warnings at the output of VS2008:

c:\boost_1_47_0\boost\phoenix\bind\detail\member_variable.hpp(54) : warning C4180: qualifier applied to function type has no meaning; ignored

Where it came from: 1) incorrectness in code 2) again MS problems. 3) boost::phoenix library not doing well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Boost devs decided that they weren't going to workaround this, perhaps since it was determined to be an error on the part of the compiler.  Here's a link:

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/1097

I think this is for general boost::bind(), but I'd bet that this probably won't be fixed.  There's a workaround suggested in that ticket.  You might try that (it just disables the warning).